# Postpone destruction of Android Bound Service

Tags: java, android, service, lifecycle

I have an Android Bound Service that handles multiple client connections. If I understand correctly, Android kills the service if there is no client connections.

At this point, however, my service may still have another thread running up to 1 minute after clients disconnect. My concern is that, if I join this thread before my service is destroyed, the destruction is delayed and it will prevent creating a new service, dropping new client connections. Is this true? Is there a way to postpone the destruction of bound services? (Like adding a fake bound count to the service when the worker thread starts and subtracting when the thread ends.)

Basically, the case I want to cover is:

1. The service have a long-running task in a separate thread.
2. The number of client connection reaches zero.
3. The service is not killed yet because the child thread is still running.

   3-1. The child thread is done, and then the service is killed.

   or

   3-2. While the child thread is running, a new client binds. So the service keeps running.

Comment: Is IntentService a possible alternative? [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly how a `Service` works that is started with [`startService()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)).
Commonly one starts the service with that call before each binding to the service.

`stopSelf()` or `Context.stopService()` will stop the service immediately or as soon as all bounders are undbounded.